# Restrict user form input in my HTML page until my Python function finishes running, Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a form with about 8 user inputs, I'm using Flask for this project. There is a button that calls a function in my python code that does XYZ, but it takes a bit of time, about 5 seconds. My problem is that if a user enters input, hits the button, and then enters more input (changes their inputs), the entire program crashes. I want to restrict user input until the function is done running

```
START <input type="text" name="set_start_freq" onchange="submit()" max="9999999999" value='{{template_data_dict["start_freq"]}}' disabled> <br><br>
STOP <input type="text" name="set_stop_freq" onchange="submit()" max="9999999999" value='{{template_data_dict["stop_freq"]}}' disabled> <br><br>
```

I have about 6 others that go along with this ^^

Adding disabled to the forms works to disable them, but not to re-enable them. I'm using

```
$(function() {
      $("input").attr("disabled",false);
});
```

to reset the forms, making them 'enabled' once the page loads. Once another button is hit though, the forms are not re-disabled. I want the forms to be disabled while the page is loading, then re-enabled once the page is finished loading.

I've also tried disabling the entire form, that didn't get me anywhere.

Comment: You can add to the `onchange` attribute to first make the input read-only. It would look like this: `on Hange="this.setAttribute('readonly', '');submit()"`. You will also need to remove the `readonly` attribute when your function completes.

Comment: How would I toggle that? The function in question is running in my Python code, so I would need to only do this temporarily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing.

```
<script>
    $('.button').click(function () {
        $('input').removeAttr("disabled")
    });

    $('.button').click(function () {
        $('input').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });

    $(function() {
        $(".auto_submit_item").change(function () {
            $("config_form").submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try to disable the button Until program function ends :**

- First add that when the button is pressed it is disabled .
- Then in the function that takes 5-6 seconds write button enable code at the bottom.

```
def func():
    # Write disable button code here
    # Code that take 5-6 sec
    # Write enable button code here
```

*I don't know flask properly but know only basics hope that would give you an idea of how to do that.*

Comment: If it works mark it as correct answer so others can see that it is working.